# Git copy code base and keep updates

Tags: git, bitbucket

We have built a small cms we want to use as base for all our projects. This cms is located in a repo on bitbucket. Our present procedure when starting a new project involves cloning "cms" then we delete git folder and run:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://xxx@bitbucket.org/myuser/newproject.git 
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
git push -u origin master
```

It works so far fine, the issue start when we have updates on "cms" and we want to copy them to the children projects. We have a "core" folder so it won't break the app.

I has been reading about mirroring [here](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/#mirroring-a-repository-in-another-location):

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/repository-to-mirror.git
Set the push location to your mirror.

cd repository-to-mirror.git
git remote set-url --push origin https://github.com/exampleuser/mirrored
```

But it seems mirroring copies all branches in this case is not what we are looking for, any ideas?

Comment: By the way, you mention that cms changes are isolated from app changes to some degree; so it sounds like what you *really* have is a core module that's a shared dependency for several apps.  Is there really an advantage to embedding its source code in those apps?  If so, see my answer below, but it might be more natural to just build the cms project as a library and include that as a build-time dependency.  (Depending on language and tooling; but for example a core.jar if this is java, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you specifically don't want to see all the history of the cms system in the newporject repo?  Still, you could keep the relationship to the cms repo to make this easier.

```
git clone --depth=1 cms
git remote rename origin cms
git remote add origin https://xxx@bitbucket.org/myuser/newproject.git
git push -u origin master
```

This assumes that the commit you want to copy is on the default branch of cms (but the procedure you spelled out above suggests that it is, so that should be ok).

By doing this, you start newproject with *the same* commit as is in your cms repo, rather than a new commit with merely the same tree.  And you keep the cms as a second remote, so you can easily fetch/pull/merge cms changes.

```
git pull cms master
```

Comment: Note, you might want to change the tracking settings so that when you pull from cms it goes to a branch other than master in newproject, depending on your branching strategy; but that's not a big deal either.